# Mass import of multiple tables -- Major problems

Tags: import

For the past three weeks, I've been trying to import accounts / contacts / leads from an old CRM into SalesForce and haven't been able to do so 100% successfully. Our accounts table has 90,000+ records, contacts about 5,000, and leads 80,000+.

I've worked with their support a few times and they've helped to a certain extent (I realized I'd needed to filter out duplicates, do some clean-up on certain fields so they'd import successfully, etc.) However, it seems like their techs are daunted by the sheer number of records. Last week one of their techs was supposed to import a bunch of contacts we'd had trouble importing and ended up importing them with mismatched fields. I had to start from square one.

This morning, starting with a completely empty database (no accounts/leads/contacts), I attempted to import our 90,000+ list of accounts. I removed all duplicates (about 50), and split the file in half (can only do 50,000 at a time). I was able to get about 80,000 of them in, and each time I imported it said 100% successful with no errors. I even tried importing only the Account Names, in case some of the other fields were causing problems. I tried the import wizard as well as the other import, no luck. I've done about 10 imports today, all come back as 100% successful, yet 10,000 accounts are still missing.

At this point, I'm a bit desperate. I guess essentially my question now is what do I do? Their tech support hasn't been helpful, and obviously their data import is not working out. My company has been paying for SalesForce for almost a month now and we haven't been able to use it. Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing your Accounts/Contacts/Leads using the [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader). The Data Import Wizard [is not recommended for importing more than 50k records](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=when_to_use_the_data_loader.htm&language=en).

If you use the Data Loader, you will get a results CSV file back that will include the Salesforce Id of each record that was created, or a message indicating why a particular record was not able to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you view the following YouTube video series titled [Data Import How To's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZMhSe8MSxI&list=PLnobS_RgN7JZaD_Fq8uh3b2AA8olsj1Qk). Its a series of 5 videos that explains data preparation, data load sequencing along with which tools to use and when to use them. In your case, it sounds like you're going to want to use Data Loader.

Data preparation and cleansing before loading is essential. Contacts are typically related to Accounts. This requires Accounts to be loaded before Contacts. This is and other things is explained quite well in the video series I've linked to above.